# Asp.net MVC Export Table to Excel | Foreign Key Display

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, excel, foreign-keys

I want to export to excel a list of students from database.

I successfully exported my filtered data to an excel file.

It looks like this:
[image]

The thing is that I want to display information from tables the id's refer to  instead of fields with ID that contains id's.

For example, there is a table called "Group" it contains "GroupID" ,"Name" and "Number"

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Group] (
    [GroupID]      INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    [Number]        VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([GrupaID] ASC)
);
```

So I want in excel file in the column where "GroupID" to display data from "Group" table ,so instead of GroupID which is "7" to show something like Name+Number from the Group Table.

Here are some project info :

-the student table I want to save in excel file

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student] (
    [Nume]          VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    [Prenume]       TEXT         NOT NULL,
    [Nota]          INT          NOT NULL,
    [GrupaID]       INT          NOT NULL,
    [ConducatorID]  INT          NOT NULL,
    [TPracticaID]   INT          NOT NULL,
    [PerioadaID]    INT          NOT NULL,
    [StudentID]     INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [LocPracticaID] INT          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StudentID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Student_ToTable_1] FOREIGN KEY ([ConducatorID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Conducator] ([ConducatorID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Student_ToTable_3] FOREIGN KEY ([PerioadaID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Perioada] ([PerioadaID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Student_ToTable_2] FOREIGN KEY ([TPracticaID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tpractica] ([TpracticaID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Student_ToTable_4] FOREIGN KEY ([LocPracticaID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[LocPractica] ([LocPracticaID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Student_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([GrupaID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Grupa] ([GrupaID])
);
```

I stored session info for the export function

```
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(grupString))
                {
    //Filter
                    student = student.Where(s => (s.Grupa.Specialitate + s.GrupaID).Contains(grupString));

                }
//Session storing student        
                Session["student"] = student.ToList<Student>(); ;
                return View(student);
```

Here is the export function:
Modified Code inspired by Hadi Hassan's reply :

```
public void ExportToExcel(string grupString)
       {
            var student = (List<Student>)Session["student"];



            var gv = new GridView();

           gv.DataSource =(from e in db.Student
                           select new 
                            {
                                Nume = e.Nume,
                                Prenume = e.Prenume,
                                Nota = e.Nota,
                                Grupa = e.Grupa.Specialitate+" "+e.Grupa.Numar,
/* The problem with cell space happens here ->**Conducator = e.Conducator.Nume+" "e.Conducator.Prenume ** when i try to make this cell made from adition of 2 string like i did before 
here **Grupa = e.Grupa.Specialitate+" "+e.Grupa.Numar,** -here the string are short and fit in the cell but when i try to do the same here 
 **Conducator = e.Conducator.Nume+" "e.Conducator.Prenume **, the strings are a little longer and throws and exception
 */
                                Conducator = e.Conducator.Nume, 
                                Tpractica = e.Tpractica.Tip,
                                Perioada =e.Perioada.An,
                                LocPractica= e.LocPractica.Denumire,
                               }
                               ).ToList(); 


            gv.DataBind();


            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=DemoExcel.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

            Response.Charset = "";
            StringWriter objStringWriter = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter objHtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter);

            gv.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter);

            Response.Output.Write(objStringWriter.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();       
        }
```

Now i am able to show the data but it **shows all the data but it is not filtered** anymore and if the text in a cell  from a row is longer than title of the column its from than it throws and exception.

After the modification the Excel file looks like this 
[image]

1)How do i export the filtered data only ?
2)How to expand the cells so i can display longer text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the following

```
public void ExportToExcel()
        {
            var student = (List<Student>)Session["student"];
            var groups  = **YourDBContextGoesHere**.Groups.ToList();

            // extract new result from the student dbset and join it 
            // with groups dbset to get the name
            // Note: only one trip to the db to get the group names since
            //       the student already stored in the session
            var result  = from s in student
                          join g in groups on s.GroupID = g.GroupID
                          select new { // you can define a ModelView with whatever properties you want inside, but I will assume that you want the following
                             Nume = s.Name,
                             Prenume = s.Prenume,
                             Nota= s.Nota,
                             GrupaID = g.Name, // here you put the name of the group
                             ConducatorID =s.ConducatorID,
                             TPracticaID = s.TPracticaID,
                             PerioadaID = s.PerioadaID ,
                             StudentID = StudentID,
                          };
            var gv = new GridView();
            gv.DataSource =result.ToList(); // here you put the result
            gv.DataBind(); 

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=DemoExcel.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";
            StringWriter objStringWriter = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter objHtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter);
            gv.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter);
            Response.Output.Write(objStringWriter.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
```

hope this will help you

Comment: Inspired by your reply Hadi Hassan, i modified the code like this

Comment: kindly mark it as answer and vote up if it helped you, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for the problem above :

```
public void ExportToExcel(string grupString)
       {
            var student = (List<Student>)Session["student"];
            var groups = db.Grupa.ToList();
            var result = (from e in student
                          select new
                          {
                              Nume = e.Nume,
                              Prenume = e.Prenume,
                              Nota = e.Nota,
                              Grupa = e.Grupa.Specialitate + " " + e.Grupa.Numar,
                              Conducator = e.Conducator.Nume+" "+ e.Conducator.Prenume,
                              Tpractica = e.Tpractica.Tip,
                              Perioada = e.Perioada.An,
                              LocPractica = e.LocPractica.Denumire,
                          }).ToList();



            var gv = new GridView();

            gv.DataSource = result;


            gv.DataBind();


            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=DemoExcel.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

            Response.Charset = "";
            StringWriter objStringWriter = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter objHtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter);

            gv.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter);

            Response.Output.Write(objStringWriter.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();



        }
```

I was abble to export all data and filtered to excel 
Thank you Hadi Hassan for help.

Comment: please tick the check sign near my answer and vote it up since it helped you

Comment: Did so ,but i can not vote since i have less than 15 rep.